# keyboard back-light not working in Realme book but works in windows dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, backlight

I have dual boot windows 11 and ubuntu 20.04. My keyboard backlight is working in Windows 11 but not in ubuntu. I tried enabling it in settings but I can't find any option to do so.

Comment: please help me i cant see the keyboard

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, what is your keyboard and computer mode and manufacturer? And what setting you tried to enable?

Comment: I am using the realme book i3 version and the inbuilt keyboard

Comment: Try `Fn+F7`, if this doesn't work then find another way. Such as asking to a manufacturer.

Comment: `FN+F7` does not work but pressing just `F7` works thanks